# 'npm install --only=dev' deletes existing packages

Tags: node.js, npm-install

While working on a node project, I am having trouble separating installation of application and test dependencies using *npm*. I am using node version **8.1.2** and npm version **5.0.3**.

To elaborate, I am using docker to create *production* and *test* images for my node application with the idea that the *production* image will have only the application dependencies installed (e.g. aws-sdk, xml-builder). I am doing this by running `npm install -q --only=prod` in the *production* docker image.

The *test* image extends the *production* image and installs the test dependencies (e.g. chai, mocha) on top of it. This is achieved by running `npm install -q --only=dev` command in the *test* docker image. The purpose of this exercise is to create a clean *production* image that doesn't have unnecessary packages.

But when I execute the latter *npm* command (`npm install -q --only=dev`) it removes the packages installed by the first install. I'm doing the same thing in another project that uses an older version of npm and node and it works fine.

Did something change in the latest version of npm? If so is there another prescribed way of achieving the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not because of the new version of Node.js, but because of the new version of *npm* that is bundled together (version 5).

In your case you could do one of these:

- Execute first `npm install --only=prod` in your production image, and then just `npm install` in your test image.
- Deleting *package-lock.json* after the first *npm install*.
- Using the option `--no-package-lock` in each *npm install*.

The new npm version uses a new file called *package-lock.js*, the one producing this behaviour, more info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json).

EDIT:

I just found out this is an issue with *npm*, it seems [it will be fixed in the next release](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16967). At the moment the workarounds I wrote above should work.

Comment: Thank you! I would up vote the answer except I can't since I don't have enough reputation in this neighborhood. :)

Comment: @NishantTrivedi I took care of that ;)

Comment: This issue was fixed in npm 5.1.0